# RegEx Search Method Returns AttributeError on Qwiklabs but not on local computer

Tags: python, regex

Given log with format of

```
Jan 31 00:16:25 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO: Closed ticket [#1754] (noel)
Jan 31 00:21:30 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: The ticket was modified while updating (breee)
Jan 31 00:44:34 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: Permission denied while closing ticket (ac)
Jan 31 01:43:10 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: Tried to add information to closed ticket (jackowens)
Jan 31 01:49:29 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: Tried to add information to closed ticket (mdouglas)
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import operator
import re
from collections import defaultdict

errors = defaultdict(int)
per_user = {}

file = open("syslog.log")
#line = file.readline()
COUNT = 0

for line in file:
   #Set regular expression to find lines containing INFO:. Contains 3 groups)
  info = re.search(r"ticky: (?P<logtype>INFO|ERROR): (?P<logmessage>[\w].*)? \((?P<username>[\w]*)\)$", line, re.MULTILINE)
  entry_type = info.group("logtype")
  entry_message = info.group("logmessage")
  entry_user = info.group("username")

  if entry_user not in per_user:
    per_user[entry_user] = {"INFO": 0, "ERROR": 0}
   # per_user[entry_user] = {"username": entry_user, "INFO": 0, "ERROR": 0}
  per_user[entry_user][entry_type] += 1 

  if entry_type == "ERROR":
    errors[entry_message] += 1

file.close()
```

May be I'm going crazy, but is there a reason that the above code creates  `entry_type = info.group('logtype') AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

This regex worked fine locally but gives the above error in Qwiklabs.  As far as I know, they are using an up to date version of Python.  I've tested the matching patterns with regex101 and grouping seems to be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Note I've also substituted the literal spaces with \s and still get working on my machine and the AttributError in the lab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `if/else` statement as you probably have lines where your expression does not match. Note that I also deleted the `re.multiline` flag as you're iterating over your lines anyway:

```
info = re.search(r"ticky: (?P<logtype>INFO|ERROR): (?P<logmessage>[\w].*)? \((?P<username>[\w]*)\)$", line)
if info:
    entry_type = info.group("logtype")
    entry_message = info.group("logmessage")
    entry_user = info.group("username")
```

---

If you want to have it all in one go, use `re.finditer()` in combination with `.groups()`:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"ticky: (?P<logtype>INFO|ERROR): (?P<logmessage>[\w].*)? \((?P<username>[\w]*)\)$", re.M)

for match in pattern.finditer(data):
    type, message, user = match.groups()
    print(message)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/WtU9hD/1).

Comment: So your regex and mine make the same matches.  Okay on the Multiline statement.  Thank you.  I guess that could be a possibility but as far as I can tell from the prompt I'm given.. the lines in the syslog file I'm given either have one or the other and with that pattern.  I'll try the if statement to see if that works.  Thank you again.